# Can you use other variables in a Google Tag Manager Constant?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm looking to create a GTM Constant that:

1. Is a regular expression that's used as a Pattern in a Regex Table variable
2. Is composed of other Constants that are just text strings, to be used in that Regex Table as well as others (where I need the text strings individually)

Do GTM Constants only accept plain text strings or will they also accept other variables (which are themselves just plain text strings)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use variables whenever the "brick" symbol shows up after the field:

[image: GTM input field for constant type of variable]

That includes constants. Philosophically I would have an issue with constants that are not constant, but that's just me.

Comment: Thank you!

To address your philosophical concern, all the constants are constant, one of them is just a regex pattern composed of sub-constants.

To confirm then, because there's no brick symbol on a trigger limiter, I can't use variables in it?

Specifically, I'm trying to limit an "all clicks" trigger to just fire on elements that we're tracking by using that aforementioned Regex pattern constant.

Comment: I think for that you'd usually use a "proper" constant and set "matches regex" as condition. But basically, not, you cannot use variables there.